# reset dropdownlist using knockout

Tags: c#, asp.net, knockout.js

I'm quite new to Knockout and am having an issue resetting my cascading dropdownlist when I select the default option.

This is my code at the moment

**JS**

```
/// <reference path="../knockout/knockout-3.4.0.debug.js" />
/// <reference path="../jquery/jquery.min.js" />

var deal = function () {
var self = this;

self.ManufacturerOptions = ko.observableArray();
self.VehicleManufacturerId = ko.observable();
self.RangeOptions = ko.observableArray();
self.VehicleRangeId = ko.observable();

var Deals = {

    ManufacturerOptions: self.ManufacturerOptions,
    VehicleManufacturerId: self.VehicleManufacturerId,
    RangeOptions: self.RangeOptions,
    VehicleRangeId: ko.observable(self.VehicleRangeId),

};

self.Deal = ko.observable();
self.Deals = ko.observableArray();
GetManufacturers();

function GetManufacturers() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:47633/api/Vehicle/GetManufacturers',
        type: 'get',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (dataReturned) {
            self.ManufacturerOptions(dataReturned);
        }
    });
}

self.manufacturerChanged = function (obj, event) {
    var manufacturerId = $("#Manufacturer").val();
    GetRanges(manufacturerId);
}

function GetRanges(manufacturerId) {
    return manufacturerId ? $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:47633/api/Vehicle/GetRanges?manufacturerCode=' + manufacturerId,
        type: 'get',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (dataReturned) {
            self.RangeOptions(dataReturned);
        }
    }) : null;
}
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new deal());
});
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>DealBook</h1>
<div data-bind="if: Deal">
<div>
    <h2>Update Deal</h2>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Manufacturer: <select id="Manufacturer" data-bind="options: ManufacturerOptions, optionsCaption: 'Select Manufacturer', optionsValue: 'cman_code', optionsText: 'cman_name', value: Deal().VehicleManufacturerId, event: { change: manufacturerChanged}"></select></p>
    <p>Range: <select id="Range" data-bind="options: RangeOptions, optionsCaption: 'Select Range', optionsValue: 'cran_code', optionsText: 'cran_name', value: Deal().VehicleRangeId, event: { change: rangeChanged }"></select></p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="dealCreateContainer" data-bind="ifnot: Deal()">
<div>
    <p>Manufacturer: <select id="Manufacturer" data-bind="options: ManufacturerOptions, optionsCaption: 'Select Manufacturer', optionsValue: 'cman_code', optionsText: 'cman_name', value: VehicleManufacturerId, event: { change: manufacturerChanged}"></select></p>
    <p>Range: <select id="Range" data-bind="options: RangeOptions, optionsCaption: 'Select Range', optionsValue: 'cran_code', optionsText: 'cran_name', value: VehicleRangeId, event: { change: rangeChanged }"></select></p>
</div>
```

I can set the default value for the ranges by `self.VehicleRangeId(null)` but I cannot seem to clear the dropdownlist.  I thought I might be able to set the options - `self.RangeOptions(null)` but that clears the dropdownlist including the default value.  Can someone give me a pointer or explain what I need to do?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you have default value? May you can set to `RangeOptions` only that value like `self.RangeOptions(['My Default Value'])`?

Comment: Hey @feeeper, thanks for the comment.  I didn't have a default value but you did give me an idea to fix it.  I used `self.RangeOptions([])` and that blanked out the values for me.  Many thanks.  I don't know if you wish to post the answer and i'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks @feeeper.  Marked it as answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have default value you can just overwrite your `RangeOptions`:

```
self.RangeOptions(['default value'])
```

otherwise, you can clear all your range options like this:

```
self.RangeOptions([])
```